# Splitting text file into double words using c#

Tags: split, c#-2.0

I have text file. I want to segment the text into double words.
The input like: `

```
str=I am currently enrolled in a PhD program
```

The output must be like:

```
    I am

    currently enrolled

    in a

    PhD program
```

How can I get this output using c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.Split` in combination with a for-loop to create a list of pairs.

```
public List<string> DoubleWords(string Input)
    {
        string[] Words = Input.Split(' ');

        List<string> Pairs = new List<string>();

        for(int k = 0; k < Words.Length; k += 2)
        {
            if(k < Words.Length - 1)
            {
                Pairs.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", Words[k], Words[k + 1]));
            }
            else
            {
                Pairs.Add(Words[k]);
            }
        }
        return Pairs;
    }
```

Comment: If that works for you, please feel free to mark it as an answer.

Comment: I am new to site ٍStackOverflow, please let me know how it works?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. What is meant by this?

Comment: I believe it’s a mechanism to prevent people from creating fake accounts to boost the score of a main account.

Comment: I need to add the contents of the array of the words into List<string>, in this case, how can I generate the list of pair from the contents of List<string>?